# How do I update the Local EDModel from Host SQL server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm Developing a booking system in ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework with MS SQL server in VS2012

I deployed the Pages on Web host and SQL Server and it is working fine.

I will be going public and I will go on develop the system, to update the SQL server file I will use SQL server management studio for creating new tables.

it's like I've added some new tables to the Host SQL server then the Local EDModel is not yet updated with the new changes, then I have to do "update model from database"

My thought is to make a new web.config file that debugs the local asp files but connects to Host SQL, so I can do the update but it doesn’t work, visual studio still debugs the with localDB.

How do I update the Local EDModel from Host SQL server?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

<connectionStrings>

 <add name="ConnectionStringSQL" connectionString="Data Source=HOSTSQLServeraddress;   
  Initial Catalog=bokningslistan;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=*****;
  Password=*****;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"

  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />

  <add name="BokningslistanV3Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Bokningslistan_EDModel.csdl|res://*/Bokningslistan_EDModel.ssdl|res://*/Bokningslistan_EDModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HOSTSQLServeraddress;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=bokningslistan; User Id=*****;Password=*****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />

</connectionStrings>

 <system.web>

  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I think you are using the EF DataBase first.

Please check the value of connectionstring name in [Name].Context.cs file. (e.g. Model1.Context.cs)

For example:

```
public MessageInfoEntities()
        : base("name=MessageInfoEntities")
    {
    }
```

After that, please modify the connection string value, such as:

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

More information, please refer to: [connectionstrings-sql-server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Note: Make sure, the TCP/IP has already been enabled in the Host SQL Server.

Next, double click the Model1.edmx file=>right click the Model1.edmx[Diagram1]=>select Update Model from database.

Please check the Tables in the Update Wizard whether they are in the host sql database.

If it still use the local sql database, please try to remove the connectionstring in the web.config file. Then try again. (It will let you to select/create new connectionstring)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've already solved this issue 2 days back.

Comment: anyways, thanks for you effort. I really appreciate it. you only able to reply on this post, none other did.

Comment: haha.. thanks :) this was obviously a tough question. :)